# How to creatle table using migration in Room database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, database-migration

```
 Expected:
    TableInfo{name='role', columns={title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='role', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

I'm trying to make migration and I don't understand where is the problem. I see title is the first row, but I do not understand why. In `RoleRoom` we can see directly it is on the second place... How to fix it? :)

```
@TypeConverters(RoomConverters::class)
@Entity(tableName = "role")
class RoleRoom(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int = 0,
    val title: String
)
```

in Migration class

```
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role` (`id` INTEGER, `title` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues are that Room expects non nullables to be NOT NULL. That is `Int` and `String` are not nullable. So Room expects

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `title` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))")
```

Hence the expected has `.... notNull=true .... notNull=true` whilst the found has `.... notNull=false .... notNull=false`

However, rather than trying to interpret the `@Entity` annotated class, it is simpler to let Room do the work. That is if you

1. Create the `@Entity` annotated class(es) as required
2. Add the `@Entity` annotated class(es) to the `entities` parameter of the `@Database` annotated abstract class.
3. Compile the project (CTRL + F9).
4. From the Android View look for the java(generated) folder/directory, expand the directories and locate the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class, but suffixed with **_Impl**.
5. Within the class, locate the `createAllTables` method, and you will find code that exceutes the SQL for creating the tables with EXACTLY the SQL that Room expects.

   1. Note that the code for **room_master_table** should be ignored as Room will create the table and populate it itself.
6. Copy the respective SQL and use that.